# $\sum_{i=1}^{n} r^{i} \leq C r^n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $0<r<1,$ and $1\neq n\in \mathbb N.$

> Question: Can find constant $C(n)>0$ so that   $\sum_{i=1}^{n} r^{i} \leq C r^n$?

Comment: Clearly no. Send $r$ to zero and observe that the right decays faster than the left.

Comment: @T.Bongers. Thanks. If I understood correctly: If we fix $r,$ and take limiting $n$ to infinity. Then the above inequality is not possible. But what happens if fixed $n$? Can we say any thing?

Comment: @MathLearner, the left-hand side is a geometric progression, compute it explicitly, then it should be easier to see what can be done.

Comment: @Hayk:Thanks a lot.